# Multiple node.js programs running at the same time

Tags: node.js, express, port

I have one node app running and I want to try the express framework while node is running the other process, but when I run the express sample app it says that:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
at errnoException (net.js:776:11)
at HTTPServer.Server._listen2 (net.js:915:14)
at listen (net.js:942:10)
at HTTPServer.Server.listen (net.js:992:5)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/omar/webServer/app.js:35:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
```

I know that this happens when you try to run both node programs at the same port but I'm using in one app port 3000 and the other 8080, so I don't know if one node instance blocks out the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Netstat to see listening ports and processes:

```
netstat -ntlp
```

You can select any other port for your `express` example (8081, 8082, etc) or kill program that uses 8080 port by PID.

Comment: Thanks I had something holding 8080 port.

Answer (score 0):

You can have nginx infront of your node apps (running on different ports)

Otherwise, just pass in a different port to your app:

```
$ NODE_PORT=8080 node app.js
$ NODE_PORT=8081 node app2.js
```

app.js

```
var port = process.env.NODE_PORT;
```

Answer (score 0):

That means you have a node process that is currently running usually. Try killing all your node processes and then trying again making sure each app is using a different port to listen on.